# Can I create a new partition from the free space inside my reiserfs-formatted /home partition?

Tags: filesystems, partition, size, reiserfs

Ok, I have Ubuntu installed but I want to install Windows also (dual-boot). Problem is, I don't have a free partition. I have my root partition (15 GB), and my /home partition (300 GB). The home partition has about 50 GB free space, and it's formatted reiserfs. I've heard about tools like resize_reiserfs, and I even tried it yesterday - I shrunk my /home partition (it's on /dev/sda6) with the command:

```
resize_reiserfs -s -20G /dev/sda6
```

After that gparted showed that the partition itself was 280 GB, but there was no way to create a new partition from the 20 GB. I ended up running

```
resize_reiserfs -s +20G /dev/sda6
```

to restore my /home partition to its previous size.

Comment: I went to the resize/move dialog in gparted, but it was showing the partition already as 280 GB size. However there was no unallocated space following it (which I could have used to make a new partition). It's as if those 20 GB became 'lost'. I eventually ran resize_reiserfs again so I could at least regain that lost space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resize_reiserfs` shrinks the file-system only, not the partition itself.   Quoting from [here](http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/nix/disk/general/disk14-ReiserFsResize/single/):

> However shrinking a partition is probably more complicated: you should first use resize_reiserfs to shrink the filesystem (the on-disk data-structure) and then only use fdisk to shrink the partition (the space allocated on the disk).

See [here](http://justlinux.com/forum/showthread.php?t=104847) for an explanation.

You can use gparted to combine both steps into one.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do everything you want entirely within gparted. It can resize the reiserfs partition, create the NTFS partition, and possibly even format it for you.

You don't actually need to format it from Linux, since the Windows installer will do that, but it will help avoid errors if you concentrate such destructive operations all within a single program run.

Comment: So I don't need to run resize_reiserfs before that? Would gparted make sure that files or file fragments (if any) that are in the last 20 GB get moved to the first 280 GB, so I don't lose any data?

Comment: Quoting the [parted user manual on the resize command](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_chapter/parted_2.html#SEC25): "...Parted does not require a file system to be "defragged" (Parted can safely move data around if necessary)." GParted is just a GUI on top of command line parted, so this applies.

Comment: Great, I'll try this then.